# Sent post request using Zend_Http_Client

Tags: php, http, zend-framework, post

I want to send a post request with a url redirect to a request page. Jest think request page currently use for handle submit form.

I tried the following code to my request page.

```
<?php

$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Request come to the page\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);

if (isset($_POST)) {
        $stringData = $_POST['user'];
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
}

fclose($fh);
echo 'page found';
```

I tried `Zend_Http_Client` to do that. This is my simple action.

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/test/test.php');

    $client->setParameterPost(array('user' => 'dinuka'));
    $client->setConfig(array('strictredirects' => true));

    $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST); 
}
```

Now request send to the test.php. But not redirect to the `http://localhost/test/test.php` page. I want send request + redirect. I asked this question previously. But it closed as pure question. Please help me. I haven't good knowledge about http request. What is the `strictredirects`?

Comment: Could you clarify your question please? what do you mean by "send a post request with a url redirect to a request page" ?

Comment: @Liyali - When you submit the form, Send parameter to form action url and redirect to the that url. I also want to do that, but with out form.

Comment: If you always want to redirect your action to /test/test.php, why don't you just do it using a redirector?

Comment: @Liyali - Is it same thing? I think no. When redirect to the request page with out post request if (isset($_POST)) { } not work. Got it ?

Comment: I'm confuse but not really, you said "Now request send to the test.php. But not redirect to the http://localhost/test/test.php page.", what are you trying to do exactly? Sending the request and redirecting afterwards without any parameter? What's the point of doing this?

Comment: @Liyali - just think i have a form. its action set to 'localhost/test/test.php' page. When i submit the form it send the post request and redirect to the test.php. I don't know what is the real word for explain that. Now i can send post request using http client. But it not goes to test.php. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think this might cover the basics of what you want:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        //set form action to indexController nextAction
        $form = My_Form();
        $form->setAction('/index/next');
        //asign form to view
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    public function nextAction() {
        //if form is posted and valid
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
                $data = $form->getValues();

                //Do some stuff
            }
        } else {
            //if form not posted go to form in indexAction
            $this->_forward('index');
        }
    }
}
```

it seems as though this the form of your question, but what you really want to know is how send post data in a redirect instead of get data, if I'm on the right track please
comment on how else we can change this to help you solve your problem.

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/test/test.php');

    $client->setParameterPost(array('user' => 'dinuka'));
    $client->setConfig(array('strictredirects' => true));

    $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST); 
}
```

I get the idea that what you want with this piece of code is to submit a post request to this url and to redirect your browser there at the same time.
This should be possible and according to what I can find it is supposed to be as simple as `$response->location` but I can't make it work. `->location` is supposed to be a header element but I can't find it. Maybe one of our other gurus can help.

Comment: I can redirect after send post request. But it is not really want. When call to $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST); it also should redirect. I don't know how i explain that.

Comment: I think @Liyali probably has the reason this won't work. It's likely most servers are defaulted not to allow this type of activity (browsers are likely the same). I couldn't even make it work on my own server. You might want try the hidden form method.